# Drywall Under Tongue and Groove?

Tags: tongue-and-groove

We've removed damaged drywall on our bathroom walls, and would like the walls to be thin tongue-and-groove planks. Is anything material except the tongue and groove required on the studs?

Comment: What's "tongue and groove"? Dimensions? Species?

Comment: Your fire codes probably require you to put 1/2" DW on the walls, and 5/8" DW on the ceiling, minimum.

Answer (score 1):

You should be careful in your choice of wall paneling material and its preparation. Not all T&G planks are suitable for walls period, and fewer still are suitable for bathrooms. Ensure your planks are sealed on all sides to minimize risk of warping.

For more flexibility, install a standard drywall wall surface. Then you can attach decorative paneling over that without compromising critical functions of the wall.

Comment: Wow, I totally disagree! you would not want a vapor barrier on the wall this would really set up a problem if there is already one on the outside. Any tong and grove should be fine for a wall. I have made some awesome patterns out of cedar  cut on 45's creating a small diamond in the center of the wall and worked out it was a real selling point on 1 house.

Comment: I wouldn't say "any". My folks have a lake home with 1/4" pine t&g on the walls over foil-faced insulation panels. In the winter, when they aren't around as much, the wood shrinks to the point that you can see silver in places. I'd go 1/2" at least, or put it over a solid panel backer.

Comment: @Ed Beal Moisture barriers are a highly contentious issue.  I would suggest what Shimon Rura recommends is correct... except --  as you point out -- for bathroom walls that are opposite exterior walls.

Comment: I was thinking of exterior when I wrote that but the OP was not specific on where they were.

Comment: Good points on the moisture barrier issue. It is more contentious than I realized. Here's an article: http://buildingscience.com/documents/digests/bsd-106-understanding-vapor-barriers
I'll edit that part of my answer.

Comment: "Moisture barrier" ≠ vapor barrier.